# Война с Ослом: в IE - русские символы не отображаются

Tags: кодировка, internet-explorer, html, mysql

Добрый день, уважаемые специалисты.

Собственно я, наверное, уже надоел всем с вопросами о кодировках, но как ни странно именно они меня пока достают больше всего. Итак. Поле боя: http://stroy-zdes.ru/
Главный вражеский босс - IE, который никак не хочет отображать русский текст.

Какие средства применялись:

1. `<meta http-equiv="Cоntent-Type" cоntent=text/html; charset="windows-1251" >`
2. `lang.htaccess: AddDefaultCharset utf8`
3. `mysql_set_charset("utf8");`

Данные средства воздействия не возымели должного эффекта. У меня работает во всех браузерах, кроме IE. Проверял в опере, фоксе, сафари и хроме.

Comment: Здравый смысл подсказывает, что кодировка должна быть одинаковая везде, раз уж на то пошло.

Comment: Здравый - да, практика нет. Выше перечислено все то что я пробовал, а не то что воткнуто прямо в конкретный момент. Тоесть, если я ставил в 1 месте утф-8, логично что я менял его и в других местах.=))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В 1. нужно прописать  `charset="utf-8"`.

Comment: > Тоесть, если я ставил в 1 месте утф-8, логично что я менял его и в других местах.=))  
  
Видимо, всё же, не так логично.

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta http-equiv="Cоntent-Type" cоntent=text/html; charset="utf-8">
```

Должно помочь, я думаю, что будет все ок! Лично мне помогало много раз, именно в IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что ты программируешь в notepad++ Попробуй написать HTML код в обычном блокноте и тогда всё начнёт отображаться правильно. Потом ты сможешь открыть файл в своём notepad++ и программировать там, но не меняй кодировку, пусть она остаётся нейтральной.